# Error: No ESLint configuration found in /node-package-path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, eslint

I have created one npm package,that uses webpack for bundling the source code.i am able to use my package locally with reactjs but when I try to use my package with vuejs it shows me the following errors

Error: No ESLint configuration found in `G:\development\Webdevelopment\purple_project\dist.`
    at `CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (G:\development\Webdevelopment\vue-test\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:432:19)`

I have searched a lot but no answers are satisfying.thanks in advance